# Convert RGB image into index (label) array

Tags: python, image, numpy

I have image which has many duplicated pixel.
So, I'd like to create label image.

For example, I'll use elements of arr_u_rs array as label values

```
# Load origianl image
im = Image.open(img_path)
arr = np.array(im)

# -------------------------
arr=arr.reshape(-1,3)
# Shape is (921600, 3)

# Remove duplicated pixels
arr_u_rs = np.unique(arr, axis=0)
# Shape is (65566, 3)
```

I'd like to create 65566 labels
and would like to assign each label into original image

For example,

```
Assign 0 (label) into [0,1,2] pixel
Assign 1 (label) into [3,4,5] pixel
Assign 3 (label) into [12,13,14] pixel from
[[[ 0,  1,  2],
  [ 3,  4,  5],
  [ 0,  1,  2],
  [ 0,  1,  2]],
 [[12, 13, 14],
  [ 0,  1,  2],
  [ 3,  4,  5],
  [ 3,  4,  5]]]
```

Comment: Sounds like you are looking for the `return_inverse` keyword of `np.unique`

Comment: @PaulPanzer Thanks. Using count return value by return_inverse=True looks like useful trick for creating label arrary.